# trying to spawn ball at a different rates and position (roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm very new to coding and I'm trying to get it where I can get multiple   balls to spawns at a certain speed and position

```
function ball_spawn(rate,pos)
    while wait(rate) do
        local ball = Instance.new("Part")
        ball.Position = Vector3.new(pos)
        ball.Name = "death"
        ball.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        ball.Anchored = false
        ball.Parent = game.Workspace
    end 
end

ball_spawn(0.5, -152, 50, -9)
ball_spawn(0.5, -152, 50, -9)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume your trying to spawn a few parts each time the function gets called. If this is the case, then you have to use a for loop, it is a loop that runs for a specific amount of times, and then stops.

```
local function Spawn_Ball(Position, Amount)

    for index = 0, Amount do
    
        local Ball = Instance.new("Part")
        Ball.Position = Position
        Ball.Name = "death"
        Ball.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        Ball.Parent = workspace
    
    end

end

while true do

    wait(0.5)
    Spawn_Ball( Vector3.new( -152, 50, -9 ), 6 ) -- Feel free to change the amount value.

  
end
```

I recommend taking a look at https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Loops for a in-depth explanation on for loop, and how they work. I hope this helped someone.